# Calling methods asynchronously

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I'm trying to write a background service in python 2.7 which can call multiple methods simultaneously, where each method might take longer to finish.

I want to call all methods asynchronously without waiting for job to finish.

Sample idea:

```
def run(self):
    while(True):
        Job1()
        Job2()
        Job3()
        time.sleep(10)
        print ("After sleep")

def Job1(self):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in a:
        print "Job 1 : " + str(i)

def Job2(self):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in a:
        print "Job 2 : " + str(i)

def Job3(self):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in a:
        print "Job 3 : " + str(i)
```

Comment: ....[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Running a method in a background thread:

```
import threading
...
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.methodname, args=())
        thread.daemon = True     # Daemonize thread
        thread.start()           # Start the execution
```

Source: http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2014/06/27/running-a-method-as-a-background-thread-in-python/